# Node.js not accepting unary plus operator

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

So when I send my code from a HTML `textarea` to my Node.js server to execute in the terminal via Javascript, it doesn't take the unary operator.

So this is the HTML where I enter my code:

```
<textarea rows="20" class="input" id="code" name="codearea" style="background-color: black;color: greenyellow;" autofocus></textarea>
```

These are the Javascript lines used to send my code to Node.js:

```
            var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    btn.style.display = "initial";
                }
            }

            xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/codetest/");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send("code=" + code);
```

and my Node.js script:

```
  function testCode(req, res) {
  let code = req.body["code"];
```

So after I write my code in the `textarea` of HTML, for example `print(10+2)`, it generally skips the '+' operator when the code is sent to Node.js.

Please do help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's happeningr url in not because your url is not encoded, so try to replace xhr.send("code=" + code) with xhr.send("code=" + encodeURI(code)). Hope it will work!. For more info, you can refer this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: Similar way while receiving that data you have to decode it to convert it to it's original form using decodeURI(). Article Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: No still facing the same issue , when the code is transferred from javascript to Node.js the plus operator is not being recognised.@ShivanshuGupta

Comment: try encodeURIComponent(code)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use body-parser in node application to parse data:
Step 1:

```
yarn add body-parser or npm install body-parser
```

Then add the below code into your main index file:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

and replace `xhr.send("code=" + code)` to `xhr.send("code=" + encodeURIComponent (code))`. I hope it will solve your problem.